# My Closet Smells Like Sewer - How To Fix?

Tags: plumbing

My Closet smells bad.  It's coming from this PVC pipe at the bottom of it.
[image: Pvc Pipe]

The cap on the end is easy to remove.  Inside, it looks like a pipe and I can see some clean water flowing through it (though it looks a bit odd in the picture)
[image: Clear Water]

My question is - how do I fix this?  Is it as simple as sealing off the opening with some caulk or similar?  Or does this indicate a failure somewhere else in the plumbing system and is merely a symptom of something I need to fix elsewhere?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's normal to smell gas in the plumbing downstream of any water trap. The trap provides a plug to prevent the gas from entering living space, but it's free to roam elsewhere, including out the vents on your roof.

You may be able to simply tighten the cleanout plug enough to get it to self-seal. Use the back of a ChannelLock, adjustable wrench, or large open-end wrench inside the slot to get good torque.

Otherwise, use thread paste or PTFE tape (3-5 wraps in the correct direction) to provide a better seal. I wouldn't use caulk, as it makes a mess and isn't reusable.

Comment: If it was loose I'd say just tighten it a little. But if you crank it on there w/o any dope it might be a PITA to remove next time. Plumber's putty: I guess so, but I'd have the same fear; that stuff's not for threads. I'd recommend paste instead of tape, but to each his own.

Comment: Ah! I meant thread paste. Updated.

Comment: Thank you!  I tried tightening it but once I added the tape it was perfect.  No smell anymore.